# Como pegar o valor da primeira e segunda posição de um array de string e criar um novo array com o resultado?

Tags: javascript, array, string

```
exemplo = ["(3,5)", "(23,2)", "(6,12)", "(50,8)"];


resultado1 = [3, 23, 6, 50];  

resultado2 = [5, 2, 12, 8];
```

Obs: O exemplo e um array de string onde a primeira posição resulta em "(3,5)" quero pega o valor do primeiro e segundo elemento respeitando a vírgula que está dividindo os números.

pode retorna em forma de string ou number;

```
    let strArr =  ["(3,5)", "(23,2)", "(6,12)", "(50,8)"];  
        let convertStr = []; 
        
            for (let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
                convertStr.push(strArr[i].match(/\d/g));
              }
     
console.log(convertStr);
```

Esse código acima não chegou no desejado.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Não sei se compreendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, Edu. Mas talvez essa solução te deixe mais próximo do resultado.

Não entendo muito de regex, então usei o replice() e o split().

```js
let strArr = ["(3,5)", "(23,2)", "(6,12)", "(50,8)"];
let convertStr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
  const numbers = strArr[i].replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(',')
  convertStr.push(numbers)
}

console.log(convertStr);
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado Alexsandro. Também não entendo muito regex, sua solução me ajudou!

Answer (score 3):

> **O algoritmo abaixo não faz nenhuma verificação ou validação de entrada presumindo atuar sobre entradas perfeitas. As verificações e validações da entrada devem ser implementadas pelo leitor que decidir usar o algoritimo.**

A resposta aceita está equivocada, o exercício proposto na pergunta recebe um array de strings como entrada onde esses strings são pares ordenados separados por virgula:

```
entrada = ["(3,5)", "(23,2)", "(6,12)", "(50,8)"];
```

E como resultado exibe dois arrays de elementos numéricos cujo o primeiro array são os primeiros elemento dos pares ordenados do array de entra e o segundo array são respectivamente os segundos elemento dos pares ordenados do array de entra :

```
resultado1 = [3, 23, 6, 50];  
resultado2 = [5, 2, 12, 8];
```

Segundo a Wikipédia:

> Em matemática, um par ordenado `(a, b)` é um par de objetos
> matemáticos cuja ordem de ocorrência desses objetos é significante.
> Consiste de dois elementos, digamos `a` e `b`, dos quais um, digamos
> `a`, é designado como primeiro elemento e o outro, elemento `b`, como
> segundo elemento.

O algoritmo de se constitui em percorrer a entrada em uma única passagem, usando o laço de iteração [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), e a cada par ordenado:

- separa o primeiro do segundo elemento a partir da virgula(`,`) com auxilio do método [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- Do primeiro elemento:

  - Remove o parênteses direito `(` com auxilio do método [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - Converte a string em numérico com auxilio do constructor [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#construtor).
  - Armazena o valor obtido em resultado1 com auxilio do método [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- Do segundo elemento elemento:

  - Remove o parênteses esquerdo `)` com auxilio do método `Array.prototype.slice()`.
  - Converte a string em numérico com auxilio do constructor `Number()`.
  - Armazena o valor obtido em resultado2 com auxilio do método `Array.prototype.push()`.

```js
let entrada =  ["(3,5)", "(23,2)", "(6,12)", "(50,8)"]; 

r1 = [];
r2 = [];

//Para cada string s de entrada...
for(s of entrada){
  elementos = s.split(",");                    //...separa os elementos do par ordenado pela vírgula.
  r1.push(Number(elementos[0].slice(1)));      //...remove o parentese direto, converte a string remanecente em numérico e salva em r1.
  r2.push(Number(elementos[1].slice(0, -1)));  //...Remove o parentese esquerdo, converte a string remanecente em numérico e salva em r2
}

console.log(r1, r2);                           //Imprime os resultados.
```